# Excel macro help to add timestamp and username

Tags: vba, excel, xlsm

I have been playing with the following code.  It works the first time, but then it appends another timestamp on the filename that already was timestamped before.  I would like this to create a new filename in the same directory with format `2018 Test_YYYY.MM.DD_HHMM` with the timestamp updated each time.  Bonus if i can figure out how to add the last user who modified the file!

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sDateTime As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        sDateTime = " (" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hhmm") & ").xlsm"
        sFileName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute _
          (.FullName, ".xlsm", sDateTime)
        .SaveCopyAs sFileName
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This should determine whether you have already added a datetime to the file name.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sDateTime As String, sFileName As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        sDateTime = " (" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hhmm") & ").xlsm"
        If Right(LCase(.FullName), 6) = ").xlsm" Then
            sFileName = Left(.FullName, Len(.FullName) - Len(sDateTime)) & sDateTime
        Else
            sFileName = Left(.FullName, InStrRev(.FullName, ".") - 1) & sDateTime
        End If
        .SaveCopyAs sFileName
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I got this far.  I simplified the code to just have a default name and add a timestamp to it.  That works well.  Now I am trying to create a Save As Dialog that pops up to